# Angular Route Call Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Weird problem I am having with Angular Route. I am trying to call templates from across a domain. Except I notice when I put the other domain in the route, it does not send the request.

To be clear, this is NOT a CORS issue, but an issue of a request never being sent at all. My code, and I am calling from example.com to example2.com:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {


    var app_url = "http://templates.example2.com/";

    $routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : app_url + '/pages/home',
        controller : 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl : app_url + '/pages/home',
        controller : 'homeController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : app_url + '/pages/about',
        controller : 'aboutController'
    });
}]);
```

How do I force Angular to send the request?

Comment: is the "example.com" `https://` perhaps? anything at all "interesting" in the developer tools console?

Comment: @JaromandaX Nothing, I wish it would throw an error to provide a little insight

Comment: indeed, that would make debugging easier!!! I take it both domains are `http://` (you didn't address that)

Comment: Yes both are regular http://

Comment: the only other thing that *may* be an issue is that your URLs would end up looking like `http://templates.example2.com//pages/home` ... perhaps the second `//` is the problem? (I'm clutching at straws though) - are you sure you are "allowed" to do that in angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an oversight on Angular because it throws no error at all, but you have to whitelist domains because it using $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl(tpl);

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider#resourceUrlWhitelist